# Deep Learning on a weird dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I'm currently learning Deep learning and I'm trying to create a dnn on a dataset with difficult data to learn. There is a lot of continous attributes and there seem to be little to no difference between classes.

I added noise to the datas and it seems to make my accuracy better, but I still cannot go over 55%. 
I also tried different activations (tanh, relu) and optimizer (RMSProp, Adam).

My next idea is to use an encoder,but I don't really know how to use it on my datas.

I was wondering if there is other thing that I could do to get somewhat near 75-80%.

The dataset is WineQuality (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality)

There is 11 attributes and 10 classes (from 1 to 10)

Using Keras, I tried the following where x_train is 11 attributes. :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=(len(x_train[0])), init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.01))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

After 200 epochs, I only have

```
loss: 1.0930 - acc: 0.5151
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide some more content and code, and you will increase the likelihood of a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dataset description it says "These datasets can be viewed as classification or regression tasks. The classes are ordered and not balanced (e.g. there are munch more normal wines than excellent or poor ones)".

It would therefore seem that to begin with treating it as a 10 class classification problem is not the best approach. It should either be treated as a regression problem or perhaps the scores could be thresholded to give a binary classification problem.

Furthermore, this is a fairly small dataset. It seems highly likely that a DNN (or any nonlinear model) would overfit in this setting. Have you tried simpler models?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I did tried with a simple Perceptron, multilayer-Perceptron, K-NN, Random Forest and all of them are getting around 50% as well. I think I'll have to do like you said and try to predict if it's a good wine or not.